# MySQL: SELECT Row Based on Ratio of True to False in Second Table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, nested

I have a table of media files and a second table with media file ratings.

What SQL statement should I use to select the media file from the first table with the highest ratio of positive to negative ratings in the second table?

This table below contains information related to each media file.

**Table: "media"**

```
| mediaID |
-----------
|       3 |
|      22 |
```

Given the table below; media file #3 would have a rating of 2/3 or 66% and #22 would have 1/2 or 50%.

**Table: "ratings"**

```
| mediaID | rating |
--------------------
|       3 |      1 |
|       3 |      1 |
|       3 |      0 |
|      22 |      1 |
|      22 |      0 |
```

Any help will be appreciated :) I have gotten as far as:

```
SELECT media.mediaID, (
    (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN rating =1 THEN 1 END ) Positive FROM ratings)
        /
    (SELECT COUNT( mediaID ) FROM ratings )
) AS percent
FROM ratings, media
WHERE media.mediaID = ratings.mediaID
GROUP BY mediaID
```

Also, it occurs to me that there could be a tie in ratio of positive to total votes between two or more media files. How could I have MySQL pick only one in that scenario?

Comment: Here's a solution that works in Oracle. It uses analytic functions. However I understand is that MYSQL does not have that capability. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53e2e/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    select r.mediaid, 
       count(*) as total_rows, 
       sum(rating) as id_sum,
       SUM(rating)/count(*) AS score
    from rating r, media m
    where r.mediaid=m.mediaid
    group by r.mediaid
```

If you want to report only those records with a score above a threshold such as 0.75
then add the 'having' clause

```
 select r.mediaid, 
        count(*) as total_rows, 
        sum(rating) as id_sum,
        SUM(rating)/count(*) AS score
   from rating r, media m
  where r.mediaid=m.mediaid
  group by r.mediaid
  having score > .75
```

Here's a demo [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b5851/4)

**After Comment**

One way is to sort by scores **desc** and then limit to 1 record like this [SQL Fiddle#2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b5851/37)

```
    select r.mediaid, 
     count(*) as total_rows, 
     sum(rating) as id_sum,
     SUM(rating)/count(*) AS score
from rating r, media m
 where r.mediaid=m.mediaid
 group by r.mediaid
order by score desc limit 1
```

Comment: zundarz, thank you for responding. Your query does provide a ratio for each mediaID. Do you have a suggestion as to how your query can be tweeked to select only the row with the highest ratio? I tried MAX(SUM(rating)/count(*)) AS score, but errored out :) I also tried "HAVING MAX(score)".